Looking for the name of an old East Asian sci-fi movie
I’m looking for this live-action movie I used to absolutely LOVE when I was a kid; however, I don’t remember much about it and would be so grateful if someone could figure out what I’m talking about.
I think the language was Mandarin, but I’m not 100% sure. But all I remember is that there was a group of people (I think college age?) and they fought aliens that all looked alike, and the design reminded me of a black ranger. Also, they all fence. I remember that one of the girls in the group said they had to go to the town to dance, and after she leaves, that’s when the aliens arrive.
The group goes to the town to fence these aliens, and I remember seeing the girl with a pink fan for her dance. I also think there was a brief fighting scene in a cave, but I’m not too sure about that. I remember the aliens climbing a fence while retreating and going back to their spaceship. 
I think the movie was made in the 80s. I know this is a stretch, but I would appreciate any help!

Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy SE! Please consider registering your account, which gives you access to more site features. As a registered user, you will be able to vote, and you won’t lose access to your post if you switch devices or browsers, or when your browser cookies are cleared. Registering is easy and allows you to participate fully in our community. For more info, see Why should I register my account?
